# Wie sagt man »butt dial« auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, verb, verb-usage

> Ich habe Dich zufällig angerufen.

Gibt es ein deutsches Verb für ***butt call*** bzw. ***butt dial*** ("im Sitzen unabsichtlich die Ruftaste seines Telefons mit dem Gesäß aktivieren" laut dict.cc)? Ich habe eins bei dict.cc gefunden, aber es ist saulang.

Comment: "versehentlich angerufen" trifft es besser als zufällig.

Comment: Wieso nicht zufällig? Hat es eine andere Bedeutung?

Comment: "Arschwahl" gibt's also (noch) nicht? Ernsthafte Frage. So wie "Arschgeweih" und "tramp stamp" sich jeweils entwickelt haben.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: "zufällig" is different, it means only the called guy was picked by random but not that it is a wrong call

Comment: @Marakai `Arschwahl` nutze ich im jüngeren Freundeskreis tatsächlich hin und wieder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ein wirklich geläufiges Wort dafür fällt mir nicht ein. Was am ehesten passen würde, wäre der Begriff "Hosentaschenanruf", der zumindest von Mobilfunkanbietern verwendet wird.

Wenn man von jemanden einen *butt call* kriegt, dann sagt man dem Besitzer am ehesten sowas wie "Dein Handy hat sich selbstständig gemacht" oder "Ich hab einen Anruf von deiner Hosentasche gekriegt"

Wenn mir jemand erzählen würde, dass er eine "Arschwahl" gekriegt hat, würde ich eher an einen *ass contest* denken